# MYSQLI - Increment query WHERE value per run

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, auto-increment

I am looking to see if it is possible to increment 
`$tid` by one each time, 
 so it is `$tid = 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, etc...`

This `$tid` would count the rows of the table, so `$tid=1` would echo row 1 info, `$tid=2` would echo row 2 info and so on. While I may feel this isn't the best solution, if anyone can suggest a more preferred alternative to how this can be done, that would be great.

*TL:DR*:  I would simply like to find a method where I can cycle through all the rows where `s_id = $tid` using the code example below

```
$tid = 1;

$query2 = "SELECT * FROM `SALE` 
 LEFT JOIN `SALE_ROW` 
   ON `SALE_ROW`.s_id=`SALE`.s_id 
 WHERE `SALE_ROW`.s_id = {$tid}";
$results2 = mysqli_query($dbconnection, $query2);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results2)) {

    echo '<div class="pphhold">';

    echo '<div class="pcdtstlye">Previous Details</div>';

    echo  '<div> s_id: ' . $row['s_id'] .'</div>';
    echo  '<div> p_id: ' . $row['p_id'] .'</div>';
    echo  '<div> sr_qty: ' . $row['sr_qty'] .'</div>';
    echo  '<div> s_total: ' . $row['s_total'] . '</div>';
    echo  '<div> s_date: ' . $row['s_date'] . '</div>';

    echo '</div>';

};
```

Comment: after the lat div inside the loops add this   $tid++ . it will increment the variable by one .

Comment: Can you explain the big picture? It is not clear if you want to run the query N times from 1 to N, with a different condition each time. Or if you want the number of rows retrieved by the query. Or something else.

Comment: Putting $tid++ after the last div did nothing

Comment: @Juan with this joint multiple table query, I would simply like to find a method where I can  cycle through all the rows where s_id = $tid

Comment: The query has a condintion limiting the results to `SALE_ROW`.s_id = $tid. Is that query working? I mean, after running the query, in the while loop you have access to each of the returned rows.

Comment: Looks like all you need is just `WHERE SALE_ROW.s_id <= {$maxTid} ORDER BY SALE_ROW.s_id`. Then you just loop through the result set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, you are doing a MySQL query outside the loop. It will be executed once and then you loop over the result. If you want to change your query (which I assume as `$tid` is a parameter of your query) and want to get the output for the changed query, you have to execute the query a second time. If you know all possible values of `$tid`, it could work the following way:

```
$tids = [1, 2, 3];
foreach($tids as $tid) {
  $query2 = "SELECT * FROM `SALE` LEFT JOIN `SALE_ROW` ON `SALE_ROW`.s_id=`SALE`.s_id WHERE `SALE_ROW`.s_id = {$tid}";
  $results2 = mysqli_query($dbconnection, $query2);
  $row = mysqli_fetch_array($results2);

  echo '<div class="pphhold">';

  echo '<div class="pcdtstlye">Previous Details</div>';

  echo  '<div> s_id: ' . $row['s_id'] .'</div>';
  echo  '<div> p_id: ' . $row['p_id'] .'</div>';
  echo  '<div> sr_qty: ' . $row['sr_qty'] .'</div>';
  echo  '<div> s_total: ' . $row['s_total'] . '</div>';
  echo  '<div> s_date: ' . $row['s_date'] . '</div>';

  echo '</div>';
}
```

But this is not good, as you have to execute the query multiple times. So just use `IN`:

```
$tids = [1, 2, 3];
$query2 = "SELECT * FROM `SALE` LEFT JOIN `SALE_ROW` ON `SALE_ROW`.s_id=`SALE`.s_id WHERE `SALE_ROW`.s_id IN(" . implode(',', $tids) . ")";
$results2 = mysqli_query($dbconnection, $query2);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results2)) {
  echo '<div class="pphhold">';

  echo '<div class="pcdtstlye">Previous Details</div>';

  echo  '<div> s_id: ' . $row['s_id'] .'</div>';
  echo  '<div> p_id: ' . $row['p_id'] .'</div>';
  echo  '<div> sr_qty: ' . $row['sr_qty'] .'</div>';
  echo  '<div> s_total: ' . $row['s_total'] . '</div>';
  echo  '<div> s_date: ' . $row['s_date'] . '</div>';

  echo '</div>';
}
```

Comment: That is brilliant and exactly what I want, but could $tids possibly be connected to such ability like mysqli_num_rows so it is the total amount of rows instead of a predefined 3?

Comment: If you like it, leave an upvote or accept it as an answer. And `$tids` is just an array of IDs you are selecting for. You can input whatever you like in this array, or understand and refactor the solution

Comment: Not to be too much of a pain, but could I possibly see how mysqli_num_rows could be used, please?

Comment: What for? You can just call `mysqli_num_rows($results2)` but I don't see where it is needed

Comment: So I can just have $tids = mysqli_num_rows($results2)?

Comment: No, why should you? `mysqli_num_rows` returns the number of rows in a result - is this in any way related to the initial query?

Comment: Where you've got $tids = [1, 2, 3]; for the number, is there a way to have that be mysqli_num_rows instead?

Comment: No, a) this does not make sense, b) mysqli_num_rows is only available after the query has executed. And calling the query with a value that is based on the result is not really possible ;) but why do you want to do so anyways? Have I completely misunderstood your initial question?

Comment: So there isn't a way to have the query run through an entire table? It has to be a predefined amount? That is rather limited ability.

Comment: Of course that is possible: just skip the `WHERE` clause of the query

Comment: I mean. $tids is currently restricted to getting only 3 rows. Is it possible to get all rows of where user_id = $tids ? So tids isn't restricted by predefinition

Comment: No, `$tids` restrict the IDs you are looking for. If you want to look for other IDs, just specifiy them: `$tids = [ 23, 42, 17, 4911 ]`

Comment: the table that $tids is pulling from isn't fixed. It is constantly changing, so having a set amount of rows to pull is really rather unfortunate that It has to be a fixed value and not all that is available.

Comment: You can define `$tids` on the fly through reading data from another table. Variables in PHP are not immutable

Answer (score -1):

use this function to get num of row by this

```
 $query2 = "SELECT * FROM `SALE` LEFT JOIN `SALE_ROW` ON `SALE_ROW`.s_id=`SALE`.s_id WHERE `SALE_ROW`.s_id = {$tid}";

$results2 = mysqli_query($dbconnection, $query2);
$count=mysqli_num_rows($results2);
```

now count has count of result

to find get count value from query:

```
$result = mysqli_query($dbconnection,"select count(1) FROM table");
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

$count = $row[0];
```

Comment: The user is not asking for a count, and a real count should be done using MySQLs `COUNT` to avoid having to fetch all rows

Comment: like `SELECT count(*) FROM table`?

Comment: That's what count is for ;)